# Using PHP array_combine & explode with multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, explode

Hi I need some help with forming arrays using explode and array_combine.

I am trying to combine two arrays below (qty and fooddesc) that were a result of using explode. I was trying to make the qty array the key and the fooddesc array the value using array combine but can't get the syntax right so I aborted.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Possibly I just need to change the way I am querying the data so I don't need to use explode at all?? It's driving me nuts.

I was forming the array to contain a meal plan with n number of meals that contain quantities of food and their descriptions so that I can then easily foreach the data out of the array into my html.

Here is my code and the array output:

```
// Begin Meal Plan
$sql = "SELECT notes, mealdesc, optdesc, group_concat(qty) as qty, group_concat(fooddesc SEPARATOR ',') as fooddesc 
    FROM plan p
    INNER JOIN mealplan mp
    ON mp.planid = p.id
    INNER JOIN meal m
    ON m.id = mp.mealid
    INNER JOIN foodmeal fm
    ON fm.mealid = m.id
    INNER JOIN food f
    ON f.id = fm.foodid
    where userid = 2
    GROUP by mealdesc
    order by mealdesc";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (!$result)
{
    echo 'Error';
    exit();
}

// Fetch meal data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$meals[$row['mealdesc']] = array('optdesc' => $row['optdesc'], 'qty' => explode(",",     $row['qty']), 'fooddesc' => explode(",", $row['fooddesc']));
$notes = $row['notes'];
}
// End Meal Plan
```

Here is the array that it produces: (I clipped this to show just the first meal to keep it short)

```
Array
(
    [Meal 1] => Array
        (
            [optdesc] => upon awakening
            [qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 6
                    [2] => 1/2 cup
                    [3] => 2 slices
                    [4] => 1 piece
                    [5] => 1 cup
                )

            [fooddesc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => egg
                    [1] => egg whites
                    [2] => oatmeal
                    [3] => wheat toast
                    [4] => fruit
                    [5] => berries
                )

        )
```

**EDIT**
Tried array_combine again and used count and a for loop for the meals to combine the qty and food desc and then used unset to remove the old qty/fooddesc arrays.

I don't know if it is the best solution but it works. :) Think I just answered my own question.

```
// Fetch meal data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$meals[$row['mealdesc']] = array('optdesc' => $row['optdesc'], 'qty' => explode(",",     $row['qty']), 'fooddesc' => explode(",", $row['fooddesc']));
$notes = $row['notes'];
}

$j = count($meals);
for($i = 1; $i <= $j ; $i++) 
{
$meals['Meal '.$i][food] = array_combine($meals['Meal '.$i]['qty'], $meals['Meal '.$i]['fooddesc']);
unset($meals['Meal '.$i]['qty']);
unset($meals['Meal '.$i]['fooddesc']);
}
// End Meal Plan
```

This gives me:

```
Array
(
    [Meal 1] => Array
        (
            [optdesc] => upon awakening
            [food] => Array
                (
                    [1] => egg
                    [6] => egg whites
                    [1/2 cup] => oatmeal
                    [2 slices] => wheat toast
                    [1 piece] => fruit
                    [1 cup] => berries
                )

        )

    [Meal 2] => Array
        (
            [optdesc] => 3 hours later
            [food] => 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_combine(
array_values($meals['Meal 1']['qty']), 
array_values($meals['Meal 1']['fooddesc'])
)
```

[aray_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) uses first parameter for keys, and second parameters for values, here we used values for first array as key for combined array.

Comment: Thanks Akam. How would I do that if I don't always know the exact number of meals? The meals can vary per plan. Some may have 4, some may have 8.

Answer (score 0):

Tried array_combine again and used count and a for loop for the meals to combine the qty and food desc and then used unset to remove the old qty/fooddesc arrays.

I don't know if it is the best solution but it works. :) Think I just answered my own question.

```
// Fetch meal data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$meals[$row['mealdesc']] = array('optdesc' => $row['optdesc'], 'qty' => explode(",",     $row['qty']), 'fooddesc' => explode(",", $row['fooddesc']));
$notes = $row['notes'];
}

$j = count($meals);
for($i = 1; $i <= $j ; $i++) 
{
$meals['Meal '.$i][food] = array_combine($meals['Meal '.$i]['qty'], $meals['Meal '.$i]['fooddesc']);
unset($meals['Meal '.$i]['qty']);
unset($meals['Meal '.$i]['fooddesc']);
}
// End Meal Plan
```

This gives me:

```
Array
(
    [Meal 1] => Array
        (
            [optdesc] => upon awakening
            [food] => Array
                (
                    [1] => egg
                    [6] => egg whites
                    [1/2 cup] => oatmeal
                    [2 slices] => wheat toast
                    [1 piece] => fruit
                    [1 cup] => berries
                )

        )

    [Meal 2] => Array
        (
            [optdesc] => 3 hours later
            [food] => 
        )
```